# Eclipse doesn't mark errors immediately when editing Android project

Tags: eclipse

In my memory, if I type something wrong, Eclipse will mark a error (red cross) at left hand.

But my Eclipse doesn't work so. It marks errors when I press "Run as...".

I look for related setting in preference, but in vain.

This feature works well in Java projects, but not in Android projects.

Comment: Is this with Java/JDT (in which case something is wrong) or with some other toolchain (C++/CDT, for example) in which case, that may just be how it works?

Comment: I have this trouble only in android project. When I edit normal java project, errors are marked immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Window / Preferences*, select *General / Workspace* and check *Build Automatically*.

Comment: Worked. Thank you. But now I get some delay... it's possible to speed up without updating my hardware?